# Could not load type Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption from assembly FSharp.Core

Tags: windows-phone-7, f#

I have a Windows Phone 7.5 application. I use some code in F# portable library referenced to the main C# Windows Phone assembly. When the code executes, it throws an exception

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1' from assembly 'FSharp.Core, ...
```

Is F# portable library designed to be used in Windows Phone 7.5 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in project properties of a F# portable library, under Target Framework, you will see that the target framekork you will see that the possible target are only Windows store,.Net 4.5 and silverlight 5. So windows phone is not in that category.

The only thing you might be able to try is what is described [here](http://blog.codebeside.org/blog/2013/02/24/fsharp-windows-phone-7-visual-studio-2012/) if you are using only feature of F# 2.0.

Comment: Windows Phone 7 is based on Silverlight, so it should work (with minimal effort on Microsoft side).

Comment: @VáclavDajbych Windows phone 7 is based on Silverlight 4 not silverlight 5

Answer (score 0):

When using the old F# 2.0 solution described in my [blog](http://blog.codebeside.org/blog/2013/02/24/fsharp-windows-phone-7-visual-studio-2012/), take care to not use any WP7 nuget package that references `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` indirectly (there are a couple of them), or you'll have conflicts in the Tuple type